# Alistar W+Q Combo (Headbutt Pulverize)

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do players link Alistar's Headbutt and Pulverize in an instant?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60619/how-do-players-link-alistars-headbutt-and-pulverize-in-an-instant)

How difficult is it to pull off Alistar's Headbutt and Pulverize combo? I see people do it instantly, without knocking players back when they headbutt with no walls behind and pulverizing them. I just can't seem to do it. :( Does this have to do with latency or quick fingers?

Answer (score 0):

It has to deal both with latency and your hability to quickly press Pulverize at the exact same time you released the Headbutt button...
I never managed to do it on the NA server, since I live in Brazil and used to play with 250~270 latency, now they released the Brazil's Beta Server and i'm playing with pings below 100 I can hit the combo almost 100%.

PS: Mind you, its highly suggested that you use the HeadBut WITHOUT smartcast, so you can see the exact range of it and avoid letting your Alistar to take a step forward because the enemy was outta range and you ending up hitting Pulverize before you even cast the Headbutt.

Answer (score 0):

Well, latency may affect that. The combo is pretty easy to do, once you have some practice. The idea is to **instantly** press <kbd>Q</kbd> after pressing <kbd>W</kbd>. Do not smartcast `Headbutt` if you haven't learnt the exact range of the ability.
I'd recommend you to go to a custom game and practice it on minions.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to improve your accuracy is to load up a custom game with just you against a bot. It will give you ample time to practice without being flamed by teammates. The gist of it is, you press W for headbutt, and immediately as the animation is starting, hit Q.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy. The trick is not to smartcast your Headbutt(W). As long as you are executing the skill(Headbutt) you can press Q and it will land both. So you basicly have 1-2 sec time to press Q (depending on how far away you are fromt he target). If you are close to the target you obviously have less time, but you probably can just instantly Q (Pulverize). It is pretty much independent on any latency and/or reaction times.

If you are used to using smartcast, but not used to playing alistar, you will probably have some problembs with your first few combos, but if you just dont put W on smartcast you will master it within 1-2 games.

Answer (score 0):

I play alistar a lot and it's not that difficult. The way I started learning was just spamming Q while I was on my way towards them. I eventually learned the timing but it was a good way to learn